# Where file naming is good for large scale projects in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, directory, naming-conventions

Where file naming is good for large scale projects ?

1.**Inherit until top of directory**

```
---routes
------ apis
--------- signin
------------ apis_signin.routes.js
```

2.by **Meaning**

```
---routes
------ apis
--------- signin
------------ signin.routes.js
```

3.**Simple naming**

```
---routes
------ apis
--------- signin
------------ signin.js
```

4.**Or you have other suggestions**

Answer (score 0):

"What", not "where". I personally use 3, anyway.

Comment: he asked for large scale project, not personally.

Comment: Well, I PERSONALLY use option 3, when working on large scale projects. Please double check the vocab before correcting, thank you.